# Magento2.2.6 - What is the purpose of tables which have tmp/replica/idx as a postfix?

Tags: magento2, database, products

I'm trying to **insert queries** in order to add **products** to our Magento website. I have no idea about these tables i mentioned at title like

```
catalog_category_product_index_replica, 

catalog_category_product_index_store1,catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica.
```

When i implement quires, should i insert values into those tables?
What is the purpose of tables which have `tmp/replica/idx` as a **postfix**?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Magento's developer an answer?